# JAXB unmarshalling issue

Tags: inheritance, jaxb

I am having issues unmarshalling XML using the jaxb2-maven-plugin(1.5). Basically I have in my XML document,  an element A of type B, which is a base domain class, Class A. Type B is a domain class that extends A. Now, I can see the XML coming in with the element A with xsi:type="B". But when I unmarshall it, it still returns a Java object of type A. How can I resolve this? I need to be able to get an object of type B. As long, as the XML has the notation xsi:type, it should be able to unmarshall it, correct. Or do I still need XMLAdapters, etc?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things to check:

- Is your `JAXBContext` aware of the `B` class?  You can include in the classes used to create the `JAXBContext` or add `@XmlSeeAlso({B.class})` on the `A` class.
- Is the name of the type corresponding to the `B` class `B`?  By default it will be `b`.  You can use the `@XmlType` annotation to specify a name.

**A**

```java
package forum13712986;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlSeeAlso({B.class})
public class A {

}
```

**B**

```java
package forum13712986;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name="B") // Default name is "b"
public class B extends A {

}
```

**Demo**

```java
package forum13712986;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        String xml = "<A xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:type='B'/>";
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
        JAXBElement<A> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, A.class);

        System.out.println(jaxbElement.getValue().getClass());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
class forum13712986.B
```